# VisualStudio Architecture Modelling - how to export as an image?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, architecture, modeling, domain-data-modelling

**I've generated a very large model that I need to put in a Technical Document. It wont fit its to big, over 8000 nodes and over 32000 links.**

I've tried screenshot tools but they only do vertical scrolling, not both horizontal and vertical to get the entire area.

I also Saved as XPS and opened that in IE, then exported to OneNote but the resolution is lost and nodes are unreadable.

> Does anyone have any advice on how I can get this gigantic model into
>   an image?

*Maybe if the File >Print menu was enabled when viewing a model I could Print to PDF or Print to image.*

**EDIT:**

4 yearrs later and I am still encountering this!! This time with a TIBCO model, yet this is TINY compared to last time *probably like 200 times smaller*:

[image]

Comment: ok ok, there is actually more on the Client Side of things. See here: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/707/nodesoffun.jpg/

Comment: I can't see the image at the link provided - possibly some kind of error?  I'm very keen to see it :)

Comment: @Adrian K - its there, showing the huge number of nodes, if someone can answer my question I'll show the diagram. Here's the direct image url: http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/449/nodesoffun.jpg

Comment: @Jeremy - sorry but it's not visible to me, all I get is a 207 x 43 pixel image that looks a little bit like a could be a cropped diagram, with the text: "Architecture Explorer", "Error", "Loaded 12042 nodes and 57244 links".

Comment: @Adrian -  that's it. I cant show you more of the diagram, its too big and I dont know how to, thats why I asked this question. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Danpros has posted an article on how to [Convert XPS Document To Image Files](http://www.danpros.com/2009/11/convert-xps-document-to-image-files.html) which might be your best bet: print it to XPS and convert from there.

There's also [this](http://www.blogsdna.com/3899/convert-xps-files-to-jpeg-png-gif-with-treasure-xps-to-image-converter.htm) over at BlogsDNA.